# XML to Excel using VBA

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Hi I am importing data from an existing xml file to an Excel I want the imported data to be stored in Sheet2 and not this.workbook

```
Sub ImportXMLtoList()
     Dim strTargetFile As String
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     strTargetFile = "C:\Users\pritam.panda\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqDemo1\LinqDemo1\bin\LinqDemo1.XML"
     Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I am using the above code in a module as I have an image in this.workbook I want it to be saved in sheet2 . Please suggest a work-around. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dim wb As Workbook

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 strTargetFile = "C:\Users\pritam.panda\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqDemo1\LinqDemo1\bin\LinqDemo1.XML"
 Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI Elements").Range("A1")
 wb.Close False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Workbooks.OpenXML, look into ActiveWorkbook.ImportXML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa204684%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Something along the lines of (untested code):

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= "C:\Users\pritam.panda\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqDemo1\LinqDemo1\bin\LinqDemo1.XML", _
ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1")
```

Comment: @PritamPanda, if that's the answer, post it as an answer and not a comment: as a comment the code is hardly readable. You can answer your own question and mark it as correct. In your answer, you can format your code properly and may help others in the future if they come across your question.